# Method to Delete duplicate-value nodes from a sorted linked list in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, return

I am writing a method to Delete duplicate-value nodes from a sorted linked list in c++. I'm trying to use Node* instead of void return type but facing an error because of the return statement.

My method code..

```
    Node* RemoveDuplicates(Node *head)
     {
       struct Node* current = head;
       struct Node* next_next;
       if(current == NULL)
       return;

      while(current->next != NULL)
       {
         if(current->data == current->next->data)
          {
            next_next = current->next->next;
            free(current->next);
            current->next = next_next; 
          }
        else 
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
      }
  }
```

The compile time error message i am receiving..

```
   solution.cc: In function 'Node* RemoveDuplicates(Node*)':
   solution.cc:31:6: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning 'Node*' [-fpermissive]
   return ;
   ^
```

Comment: Why are you using `Node *` even if your function doesn't return anything?

Comment: The error message is clear, read it.

Comment: You are writing in C.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type to `void`.

There is nothing valuable to be returned from the function.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't pretend to know what you are thinking, he asks you to make contracts on what is going on. Hence, declaring the return type `Node*` you must provide an output of that specific type : a Node pointer. The most likely scenario I can imagine here would be returning the current node without the duplicates at the end of the function.

```
Node* RemoveDuplicates(Node *head)
{
    // some instructions
    return head;
}
```

so you can have this kind of semantic :

```
Node* distinctList = RemoveDuplicates(head);
if (distinctList) // NULL (0 / false) if empty
{
    // some more instructions
}
```

However, if you don't need anything to go out of the function, the return type should be void (nothing).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried adding head to "return head" statement like you said but I'm getting another error message...

Comment: You should also remove the `return;` part, which is returning nothing, or at the best, replace it with `return NULL;` since you will already know in this case that removing something from nothing will become nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I will treat this as a learning exercise, and ignore the fact that it is preferable to use a std list than to implement your own linked list, and it is preferable to use new and delete to using malloc and free.

If you specify Node* as a return type, you must return a pointer to a node.  In order to answer your question, you  have to ask is: what pointer do you want to return?  As written you are deleting all duplicate pointers.  Do you want to return the last pointer deleted?  Do you want to loop until you find a duplicate and delete that?

You have two exit points in your code snippet.  The first is a plain "return" statement, which is called when the list is empty.   As written you are returning *void*, i.e. nothing.  You need to return a pointer to a Node, but you have no valid pointers, so you probably want to return a null_ptr, which is a pointer to nothing.

Now we come to the part of your question which depends on the desired behavior.  For example:

```
while(current->next != NULL)
   {
     if(current->data == current->next->data)
      {
        next_next = current->next->next;
        free(current->next);
        current->next = next_next; 
        ///  Here  you have a valid pointer you could return:
        return current;
      }
    else 
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    // if you get here, no duplicates were found, so you can return a nullptr.
    return std::nullptr;
  }
```

Will loop over your list until a duplicate is found, will delete that duplicate, and return a pointer to the remaining pointer.  If no duplicates are found, a nullptr is returned.

I leave it as an exersize to modify this to loop over all elements in the list until the last duplicate is found (hint, you will have to introduce a local variable to store the return value), and return that.

Good luck.